# How to get child of selector in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Sorry I can't explain my problem very good .
I want to get child of tag that I selected before.

I show you in simple code.

this is my html code:

```
<div class="inner">
  <div class="box">
      <a href="yaghoot.studio"></a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="inner">
   <div class="box">
      <a href="http://google.com"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.inner').click(function () {
        window.location = $('.inner > .box > a').attr('href');
    });
});
```

If click on any div with 'inner' class open the first url. 
How to set url for each div ?

Can use keyword 'this' for this case ?

Comment: Optionally if you turned the "inner" div into a <label> element that targeted the inner link, you wouldn't have to have any of that javascript at all.

Comment: I can't change html code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect because you select all the `.inner` elements within the DOM. Calling `attr()` on this collection will only return you the value of the first element in that collection.

To get a reference to the element which raised the `click` event use the `this` keyword along with `find()`:

```
$('.inner').click(function () {
  window.location = $(this).find('> .box > a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: tanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` to refer to the element being clicked, and `find()` to look down the DOM:

```
window.location = $(this).find('.box > a').attr('href');
```